# Помощь в создании MySql запроса

Tags: mysql

Есть 3 таблицы: "дома", "квартиры", "жители"

```
dom:
  id

kvartira:
  id, idom

people:
  id, idkvartira
```

```
    Получается что могут быть созданы дома, в домах квартирах, а в квартирах люди. 
    При этом могут быть пустые квартиры без людей и пустые дома без квартир.
```

Вопрос. Если мне нужно вывести дерево существующих домов, квартир жителей, можно ли сделать 1 sql запрос?
Пример массива:

```
Дом № 1
---
Дом № 2
   Квартира № 1
   Квартира № 2
        Житель № 1 
---
Дом № 3
   Квартира № 1
        Житель 1
        Житель 2
        Житель 3
   Квартира № 2
----
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Можете привести пример ТАБЛИЦЫ, которую вы хотите получить?

Comment: *можно ли сделать 1 sql запрос?* Конечно.